# AngularJs filter on nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a grouped nested object that I want to filter. The filter works only on the second group.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="grouping" value="name"  />Name
<input type="radio" ng-model="grouping" value="date" />Gender
<input type="radio" ng-model="grouping" value="jsonpath" />Hair
<input type="text" ng-model="searchInput" />

<div data-ng-repeat="(group, details) in group(reports, grouping) | filter:searchInput">
<h2>{{group}}</h2>        
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="report in details | filter:searchInput">
        {{ report.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/aF2aL/15/

[UPDATE]

I have an updated plunker, not sure if i'm on the right direction: http://plnkr.co/edit/MYkTJoAIXV2XEN6glrDQ?p=preview

Comment: Filter works on an array, whereas your `groupBy`, returns a object instead of array.

Comment: So there is no way to order groupby?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? Im having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose to put the filter on the outer repeater? Just remove it.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(group, details) in group(reports, grouping)">
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FmVTj/)**</kbd>

Comment: The purpose is to sorter and reordering the records! I've found an interesting discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286