# AngularJS ng-repeat issue with removing duplicate keys in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` to repeat the rest of data if the attribute is the same. This may not sound clear so here is an example.

JSON sample, which is an array of books

```
[{"Genre":Sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname1"},
 {"Genre":Sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname2"},
 {"Genre":Non sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname3"},    
 {"Genre":Non sci-fic,"Name":"Bookname4"}]
```

So if the book belongs in the same genre, then we would have genre type as the heading of the accordion and list the rest of the attributes for the ones whose genre is that without repeating the heading. The problem I've been encountered is that since json array of objects comes from a data model, and I can't really filter the type without repeating the genre type.

here is what I'm having where I'm trying to have heading as the Book.Genre and inside that accordion-group will have the list of all the books whose genre is the heading.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PwIrOAIT3RRaE2ijzGZb?p=preview

Comment: could you post your ng-repeat expression ?

Comment: <accordion-group  heading = {{Book.Genre}} is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled" ng-repeat="book in Book"> </accordion-group>                                        where Book is the data model

Comment: Should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24001985/2057033

Comment: so your question is missing a lot of information, first you are using a directive that group your data, etc ... you should post this info when asking, in order to help you better

Comment: I suggest to post a fiddle, to makes things clear

Comment: @Ahmad : I can't really include the angular bootstrap with fiddle, but here is what I'm having where I'm trying to have heading as the Book.Genre and inside that `accordion-group` will have the list of all the books whose genre is the heading.   http://jsfiddle.net/Uz5tM/

Comment: @Blackhole : Thanks I will try what you just linked.

Comment: So I found a solution which works for me. I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698793/angularjs-filter-on-nested-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution which works for me. I followed this [AngularJs filter on nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698793/angularjs-filter-on-nested-ng-repeat). I made a couple changes for my data model, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to tackle this problem yet either... The best solution I can think of is to simply strip out the duplicates before adding that model to your scope...

Using your jsFiddle example...

**http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/Uz5tM/1/**

```
var books = [
             {"Genre":"Sci-fic", "Name":"Bookname1"},
             {"Genre":"Sci-fic", "Name":"Bookname2"},
             {"Genre":"Non sci-fic", "Name":"Bookname3"},    
             {"Genre":"Non sci-fic", "Name":"Bookname4"}
               ];

var unique = [],
    blocked = [];

unique.push(books[0]);
blocked.push(books[0].Genre);

for (var i = 1; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (blocked.indexOf(books[i].Genre) <= -1) {
        unique.push(books[i]);
        blocked.push(books[i].Genre);
    }
}

$scope.Books = books; 
// [{Genre: "Sci-fic", Name: "Bookname1"}, 
//  { Genre: "Non sci-fic", Name: "Bookname3" }];
```

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the Genre as one of the headings or should I use this as a filter and then do the same for the Genre?

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you 've got  duplicate value in generes use track by

```
  <div ng-repeat="genere in generes track by $index"></div>
```

or if you want group you model by Genre you can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) please see that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz5tM/4/)

View :

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">

    <ul class="about-tab-titles" close-others="oneAtATime">
            <li  ng-repeat="(key ,book) in model">
                {{key}}

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="b in book ">{{b.Name}}</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])

function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    var books = [{
        "Genre": "Sci-fic",
            "Name": "Bookname1"
    }, {
        "Genre": "Sci-fic",
            "Name": "Bookname2"
    }, {
        "Genre": "Non sci-fic",
            "Name": "Bookname3"
    }, {
        "Genre": "Non sci-fic",
            "Name": "Bookname4"
    }];

    $scope.model = _.groupBy(books, 'Genre');

}
```

Comment: Still doesn't fix the issue... Been struggling with this one myself for a while